# Prove that $\sin(n\pi x)$ weakly converges to $0$ in $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $$f_n(x):=\sin(n\pi x)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in (0,1)$$ and $$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_{(0,1)}fg\;d\lambda^1\;\;\;\text{for }f,g\in L^2(0,1)$$ I want to show, that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ *weakly converges* to $0$, i.e. $$\langle f_n,g\rangle\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\langle 0,g\rangle=0\;\;\;\text{for all }g\in L^2(0,1)$$

---

Unfortunately, $$\left\|f_n\right\|_{L^2(0,1)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\frac 12\ne 0\;,$$ i.e. $f_n$ doesn't converge in $L^2(0,1)$ to $0$ (which would immediately imply weak convergence too). So, it seems like I need to prove the statement from the definition above. However, I've absolutely no idea how to do so.

Comment: You could show that the $f_n$ are pairwise orthogonal. If you know a little Hilbert space theory, you'll know that that, together with the boundedness, implies weak convergence to $0$.

Comment: This is the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate, just have to find another one with it.

Comment: do you know how to prove the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma? "Alternativelly" this is saying the fourier coefficients of a function are going to 0.

Comment: Another way is to use the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma from Fourier Analysis. It states that the sequence of fourier coefficients for continuous functions is a null sequence. Using a density argument you get weak convergence to $0$ for these multiplier functions.

Comment: Haha three people noticed the same thing ^^

Comment: My duplicate is exact duplicate ($L^2(0,1)$ and $\sin(nx)$).

Comment: @AlexR Good on you. I cannot retract and revote in on yours, so I'm leaving the other one.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can you provide a proof for "the $f_n$ are pairwise orthogonal"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma

Comment: @0xbadf00d We have $\sin \alpha \sin \beta = \frac{1}{2}(\cos (\alpha-\beta) - \cos (\alpha+\beta))$, so the orthogonality follows from $$\int_0^1 \cos (k\pi x)\,dx = \frac{\sin (k\pi x)}{k\pi}\biggr\rvert_0^1 = \frac{0}{k\pi} - \frac{0}{k\pi} = 0$$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I remember that I've proved that in the complex form in the past. How does that imply the weak convergence?

Comment: If $\{ e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space, then $e_n \rightharpoonup 0$. Modulo a constant factor, the $f_n$ are an orthonormal basis of a Hilbert space.